# TLS/SSL connection with client authentiation

Tags: ssl

I want to setup client authentication in a way that during TLS/SSL handshake when server asks the Browser for client certificate, the client certificate is retrieved from a remote Certificate Provider server application.

Is there any way to dictate the browser to use a program written in java/c++ for client certificate retrieval?

Answer (score 1):

You can't dictate browser directly. What you can do is implement a module (you'll need separate modules - a CSP module for CryptoAPI-based browsers like IE and wrappers and for Mozilla which uses PKCS#11) which will obtain certificates from remote location. The idea is that once the browser requests a certificate or certificate list from such module, the module reads information from your server.

Both modules must be installed by the user (CSP is installed to Windows and PKCS#11 driver is copied on the disk and then the browser is configured to use it), i.e. this is not automatic and can't be done by your site without user support.

Comment: In which programming language the CSP module has to be written? For Java, jvm is required. 2nd which service need to be implemented, as i see there are various crypto services? Some details about the implementation would be really helpful.

Comment: @user3027786 CSP module for CryptoAPI should be written in C or Pascal (definitely not Java). The same for PKCS#11. I am not an expert in CSP services, so I can't give you precise directions. I think you should look around for existing open-source CSP implementations.

Comment: Thanks. Actually i want a solution which is cross platform. I think going with mozilla firefox is the right track. Is configuring CSP for mozilla same as IE. I read one can setup crypto module directly in firefox but dont know how CSP can be configured for firefox. Is there any difference in impl. for IE and Firefox?

Comment: @user3027786 As I wrote above, for Mozilla you need PKCS#11 modules.